# Using UK formatted date with reactive form and ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, ngx-bootstrap

I have implemented the ngx-bootstrap datepicker module and I am having an issue when typing in a UK date formatted.

I am using reactive forms and when I type in, for example 16/08/2017 the form immediately invalidates.

If I use the date picker control pop-up and select the same date the form is valid.

I cant figure out why manually keying in a date invalidates the form but when using the date picker its valid?

Here is all relevant code:

```
  <input type="text" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue" [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" formControlName="ArchiveToDate"
                    width="50px" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                <label class="errorMessage" *ngIf="archiveForm.touched && !archiveForm.valid">{{errorMessage}}</label>
```

Here's the relevant code in my .ts file

```
     public datePickerConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig> = new BsDatepickerConfig(); 
colorTheme = 'theme-blue';

defineLocale('en-gb', enGb);
this.datePickerConfig = Object.assign({}, { locale: 'en-gb' }, { containerClass: this.colorTheme });

  this.archiveForm = this.fb.group({ 'ArchiveToDate': [null, [Validators.required]] });
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this locally, can you provide a reproduction on plunkr / stackblitz?  starter templates:

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/0NipkZrnckZZROAcnjzB?p=preview

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Parsing manual date input is known issue,
Fix will be released in rc.1